# I am confused about argument list in hosted mode in gwt

Tags: gwt

i am new in gwt.i am confused in argument list in hosted mode like -noserver,-logLevel,-out,-style.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Note: if you have `-style` for dev mode, then you're using "hosted mode" and a really old version of GWT: "hosted mode" was removed in GWT 2.0, replaced by "dev mode".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These options serve as the configuration while debugging or running the GWT application.
For example, to run a GWT application, you need to define the web server, port for the web server, Logging related information, war folder for deployment of the application etc.

For more information on this, please visit this link:
http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideCompilingAndDebugging.html#What_options_can_be_passed_to_development_mode

You might want to see this as well:
http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideCompilingAndDebugging.html#DevGuideCompilerOptions